# Awarded level 10 blacksmith achievement but I didn't raise it?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I just got the level 10 achievement for my blacksmith while I was playing on my HC character, on Rakkis Crossing. The even weirder thing is that my HC blacksmith is level 1, my softcore blacksmith is level 8 or 9. How is this even possible?
The other guy who was with me also got these achievements (level 10 bs plus "all artisan achievements" achievement).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a bug where if someone else joins your game and they have the achievement, you get the achievement too (along with some other achievements).  This is viral, so if you now join other people's games, you will grant them all those achievements as well.

Comment: +1 confirmed; I haven't upgraded the jeweler or blacksmith at all, but last night I got all achievements for both when my friend (who has them all) joined my game.  Everyone else in the game got them too.

Comment: does this happen just with artisan achievements?

Comment: @Nico: Yes, you get the 2 artisan achievements (to level 10) and a meta achieve for doing both.